# Vague kernel exception on D3D11DeviceContext Update Subresource

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-11

I am developing a class for displaying 10-bit video streams using D3D11. The solution I went for was to render each frame as a texture to a quad. As such I have a function for updating the frame/texture from a YUV surface:

```
void tenBitDisplay::SetTextureData(short int *yuvData) {

    unsigned int size = m_width * m_height, chromaSize;

    short int y1, y2, y3, y4, u, v, r, g, b;
    DWORD *data;

    chromaSize = size * 0.25;

    data = new DWORD[size];

    for(unsigned int k = 0, j = 0; k < size; k += 2, j++) {
        y1 = yuvData[k];
        y2 = yuvData[k + 1];
        y3 = yuvData[k + m_width];
        y4 = yuvData[k + m_width + 1];
        u = yuvData[size + j];
        v = yuvData[size + chromaSize + j];
        convertYUV(y1, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
        packRGB(data, r, g, b, k);

        convertYUV(y2, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
        packRGB(data, r, g, b, k + 1);

        convertYUV(y3, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
        packRGB(data, r, g, b, k + m_width);

        convertYUV(y4, u, v, &r, &g, &b);
        packRGB(data, r, g, b, k + m_width + 1);

        if (k!=0 && (k+2) % m_width == 0)
            k += m_width;
    }

    if (m_pTexture2D != NULL) {
        m_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(m_pTexture2D, 0, NULL, data, m_width * 4, 0);
    }

    free(data);
}
```

Everything executes fine up until it reaches the `m_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(m_pTexture2D, 0, NULL, data, m_width * 4, 0);` call. At some point during execution of this method, the following exception is thrown:

```
First-chance exception at 0x751EC41F (KernelBase.dll) in app.exe: 0x0000087D (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x0273D328, 0x0273C760).

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I am guessing this is a problem with the heap, stack or something else to do with memory. I just can't figure out what precisely, and I have never encountered such an issue and don't really have much knowledge about where to start with debugging it. I have checked the preceding loop to make sure there is no overrun on the buffer and everything is fine.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I had basically the same code running fine in a different application (which just loaded YUV files directly) before I moved it into the video decoding application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was updating the texture in one thread whilst another thread was calling the render method. This caused the threads to clash over the texture object. I implemented a mutex and it seems to work okay now.

Comment: Neat.  How did you go about finding that there was a threading issue?  I am new to C++ and I am trying to learn how to debug my code better.

Comment: @A.R. If I remember correctly, I just stuck some breakpoints in and stepped through.

Comment: I was trying that and wasn't having too much luck.  I then remembered that there is a 'threads' window in VS2012 and I looked at all of the stacks to find out where the problem was.  Your suggestion of using a mutex worked great too by the way.